# UILabel being referenced as an integer pointer in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

**The Goal and Problem:**

After every passing second, the value of 'regularBubbleCount' - a variable of RWGameData - increases by 1. I am attempting to display this change in value by passing the new value of 'regularBubbleCount' to the 'regularBubLabel' UILabel in the PrimaryViewController. I am attempting to do this by using the following line of code,

```
_regularBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
```

Obviously this does not work because 'regularBubLabel' is not an object of the RWGameData class where the 'timerCalled' method resides. How can I change the value of the 'regularBubLabel' from inside the RWGameData class?

## RWGameData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RWGameData : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (assign, nonatomic) long regularBubbleCount;

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL dataIsInitialized;

+(instancetype)sharedGameData;
-(void)reset;
-(void)save;

-(void)timerSetup;
-(void)timerCalled;

@end
```

## RWGameData.m

```
#import "RWGameData.h"

@implementation RWGameData

static NSString* const SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey = @"regularBubbleCount";
static NSString* const SSGameDataIsInitializedKey = @"dataIsInitializedKey";

+ (instancetype)sharedGameData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)reset {
    self.regularBubbleCount = 0;

    self.dataIsInitialized = true;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.regularBubbleCount forKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];

    [encoder encodeBool:self.dataIsInitialized forKey: SSGameDataIsInitializedKey];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _regularBubbleCount = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];

        _dataIsInitialized = [decoder decodeBoolForKey: SSGameDataIsInitializedKey];
    }
    return self;
}

+(NSString*)filePath
{
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];
    }
    return filePath;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance
{
    NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [RWGameData filePath]];
    if (decodedData) {
        RWGameData* gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return gameData;
    }

    return [[RWGameData alloc] init];
}

-(void)save
{
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[RWGameData filePath] atomically:YES];
}

- (void)timerSetup { // to be called from delegate didFinishLaunching….
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerCalled
{
            [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount++;
            /* THE ISSUE IS HERE */
            _regularBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
            [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];

    } NSLog(@"Regular Bubble Count: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount);
}

@end
```

## PrimaryViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RWGameData.h"

@interface PrimaryViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *regularBubLabel;

@end
```

## PrimaryViewController.m

```
#import "PrimaryViewController.h"

@interface PrimaryViewController ()

@end

@implementation PrimaryViewController
{
    NSString *bubbleImage;
    UIImage *backgroundImage;
    UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
    int r;
    int i;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_new.png"];
    backgroundImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    backgroundImageView.image=backgroundImage;
    [self.view insertSubview:backgroundImageView atIndex:0];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _regularBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
    _premiumBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].premiumBubbleCount];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)increment {
    if ([RWGameData sharedGameData].megaBubblePopValue == 0) {
        [RWGameData sharedGameData].megaBubblePopValue++;
        [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];
    } 

    if ([@"mysterybubble.png" isEqual:bubbleImage]) {
        [RWGameData sharedGameData].premiumBubbleCount += 2;
        _premiumBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].premiumBubbleCount];
    } else if ([@"megaBubbleLarge30.png" isEqual:bubbleImage]) {
        [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount += [RWGameData sharedGameData].megaBubblePopValue;
        _regularBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
    } i++;
}

- (IBAction)save {
    [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];
}

- (IBAction)setBubbleStatus {
    r = arc4random_uniform(400);

    if (r <= 1) {
        bubbleImage = @"mysterybubble.png";
        [_megaBubbleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bubbleImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"Roll SUCCESS. [%i] %i", i, r);
    } else {
        bubbleImage = @"megaBubbleLarge30.png";
        [_megaBubbleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:bubbleImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"Roll FAIL. [%i] %i", i, r);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I appreciate the down-votes - I will try to make my questions stronger in the future - but I would also appreciate a comment along with the down-votes if you have any information for me to work with.

Comment: I strongly recommend to focus your question to the required code.

Comment: Please remove all but the relevant code and point out the exact line of code causing the problem.

Comment: I have a few questions. First, where is RWGameData and PrimaryViewController instantiated? Does the update to RWGameData::regBubleLabel happen on the main thread?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner I have updated the topic appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamHPU You shouldn't rewrite a problem statement that you've already submitted on Stackoverflow because that would obsolote existing answers and comments. Instead, you should append new information at the bottom as necessary.

Comment: Questions should not be rewritten after they've been posted.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to have an IBOutlet in your RWGameData class, since it's a subclass of NSObject. That class has no instance (and no view) in the storyboard, so you can't hook up an IBOutlet. One way to accomplish your goal would be to make PrimaryViewController a delegate of RWGameData, and call a delegate method inside the timer's action method that would pass whatever data you need so PrimaryViewController can update its own label.

Comment: Just for clarity, it *would be* possible to instantiate a custom class and connect its outlets in a storyboard, even in a case where it would arguably be bad design (such as the one proposed by the OP).

Comment: Understood. So I will scrap that method and attempt to implement the one you are proposing. I will search around for some information on how to make PrimaryViewController a delegate of RWGameData, and how to call a delegate method from inside the timer's action method.

Comment: @jlehr, Yes, that is technically correct. You could drag in a generic object into the storyboard, and change it to your custom object. The OP's code though won't even compile unless you import UIKit, since an NSObject doesn't know anything about a label.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make the following assumptions:

Assumption #1 -RWGameData is instantiated inside the ApplicationDelegate when the application is loaded and can be referenced in the application delegate as `self.gameData`

Assumption #2 - PrimaryViewController is, as you have named it, the primary view controller in your storyboard.

Assumption #3 - You're using an NSTimer to update this count every 1 second.

Assumption #4 - Your Storyboard file is called `Mainstorybaord`

## RWGameData

Add this to your `RWGameData.h` before your class definition.

```
@class RWGameData;
@protocol RWGameStateProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)StateUpdateForGameData:(RWGameData*)data;
@end
```

Inside `RWGameData.h` add a delegate in your class definition.

```
@interface RWGameData : NSObject
@property(weak)id<RWGameStateProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

In your selector `timerCalled` add a call to your delegate informing it the data has changed.

```
-(void)timerCalled
{
            [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount++;
            /* THE ISSUE IS HERE */
            _regularBubLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount];
            [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];

    } NSLog(@"Regular Bubble Count: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount);

   /* Inform the delegate */
[self.delegate StateUpdateForGameData:self];
}
```

## PrimaryViewController

Once you have your protocol defined have your `PrimaryViewcontroller` conform to this protocol with something similar to the following.

```
-(void)StateUpateforGameData:(RWGameData*)data
{
   self.regularBubLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i",data.regularBubbleCount];
}
```

## Application Delegate

All that remains is to set the delegate on your `RWGameData` instance. You can do this by asking storyboard to provide you an instance of your primary view controller. If you're using storyboard then by default this method is empty. However, since we are going to modify the primary view controller before it is shown then we need to make a few changes and perform some of the work Storyboard already does for you.

In your ApplicationDelegate's header file create a property for a `UIWindow` and `RWGameData`.

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property(strong,nonatomic) RWGameData *gameData;
@end
```

Now that we have the properties setup you need to perform some additional work. Note that normally you don't have to perform this step when using storyboard.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{
    /// Screen Information
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];
    CGRect frame  = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];

    UIWindow* window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    self.window = window;
    self.window.contentScaleFactor = scale;


    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    PrimaryViewController *vc = (PrimaryViewController*)[sb instantiateInitialViewController];

    RWGameData *gameData = [[RWGameData alloc]init];
    gameData.delegate = vc;
    self.gameData = gameData;

    [window setRootViewController:vc];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This approach doesn't require you to tightly couple your label and game data. Instead any update to your game data can now inform your view and allows your view to select which labels need to be updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting. I have gotten to this part: "Now your probably have a selector you're using for your timer that increments the count of regularBubbleCount you should add a call to your delegate informing it that the data has changed." The selector I am using is 'timerCalled'. How can I add a call to my delegate to inform it that the data has changed?

Comment: @AdamHPU It is the other way around. You want your RWGameData to inform your delegate the data has changed. In the example your delegate object is actually  your PrimaryViewController (since it conforms to the newly created protocol). I'll update my answer using your implementation.

Comment: I am getting a warning when trying to do the 'application delegate' part. The warning is: 'Assigning to 'id<RWGameStateProtocol>' from incompatible type 'PrimaryViewController *__strong'. I am using [RWGameData sharedGameData].delegate = vc; and _window.rootViewController = vc;

Comment: @AdamHPU I fleshed out the application delegate implementation. Please note that if you're getting a retain cycle warning then you must have the property of your delegate set to strong vs. weak. Additionally, it sounds like you have not updated your ```PrimaryViewController` to conform to your protocol ```RWGameStateProtocol```

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect some of the changes you have suggested. My PrimaryViewController interface declaration in the header file now reads; @interface PrimaryViewController : UIViewController <RWGameStateProtocol> and the warning I was getting regarding the id issue has now been resolved. I also had to change the name of the storyboard to 'Main' since the file name is 'Main.storyboard' and it wouldn't reference 'Main.storyboard' for some reason. The label doesn't seem to be updating though.